# Как работает один открытый порт и брандмауэр с сокетами?

Tags: сокет, tcp

Не могу понять как работает брандмауэр и т.п. с открытием сокетов.
Допустим у нас открыт порт 80 при подключении создается новый сокет который имеет уже новую связку например х.х.х.х:1234 клиент и х.х.х.х:8081 сервер и в дальнейшем клиент и сервер будут напрямую слать запросы на эти порт, верно?
Но на сервере у нас же открыт только порт 80 как это работает?

Comment: У сервера порт всегда один и он не может меняться. Это у клиентов разные порты могут быть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, Вы немного сами себя запутали.

Вот часть вопроса: "при подключении создается новый сокет который имеет уже новую связку например х.х.х.х:1234 клиент и х.х.х.х:8081 сервер"

А почему Вы так думаете?

TCP cокет в "законнекченном" состоянии представляет из себя - на логическом уровне - комбинацию из четырых чисел: "клиентский IP, клиентский порт, серверный IP, серверный порт".

При подключении к 80-му порту в качестве серверного порта будет порт 80.

Если у Вас это не так - проверяйте, значит, у Вас открыт еще один порт.

Теперь - маленькое отступление, которое поможет понять, как работают порты.

Внизу вопроса приведен простейший "сервер", который слушает порт 1080 и для каждого поключенного клиента отправлет обработку этого подключения в процедуру doit() (в отдельном процессе)

И теперь посмотрим как создаётся соединение.

Когда сервер запущен - это соответствует строке `int  connfd=accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&clientaddr, &addrlen);`.

Чтобы запустить сервер для "прослушивания сокета" - нужно уже знать "половину" TCP - соединения - серверный адрес и серверный порт.

На этой строке сервер будет висеть, пока к нему не подключится клиент.

Как только клиент присоединился - процедура accept возвращает структуру, которая стала "полноценным" TCP соединением, и где к серверной части добавилась клиентская часть - клиентский адрес и клиентский порт, с которого и происходит подклчение.

Дальше - происходит FORK процесса, и в только что созданном процессе происходит работа с портом в точности как с файлом - у нас в этот момент уже есть файловый дескриптор fd.

Когда процесс заканчивает обработку - он закрывает "файл". Об остальном позаботится ядро системы.

Значение "5", которое передаётся при создании серверного сокета в качестве "длинны очереди" - это число, которое говорит, сколько клиентских соединений можно держать в очереди в ожидании обработки (это будет соответствовать ситуации, когда клиенты подключаются быстро, а новые процессы для их обработки создаются медленно)

Так, кол-во одновременно подключенных клиентов ограничено только ресурсами сервера, а не архитектурой соединений.

И еще раз: пускай клиенты подключаются  одного и того же IP. Но тогда клиентская ОС будет выдавать им разные порты на стороне клиента. И поэтому сервер сможет их "различить". Не говоря уже о клиентах, которые подключаются с разных IP.

```
    // server
    int main(){

        int listenfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0); //серверный сокет
        struct sockaddr_in server_addr ;

        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        server_addr.sin_port = htons(1080);

        if (bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr))<0){  // параметры сокета
            printf ("Error in bind\n"); return 0; } 

        if (listen (listenfd,5)<0) { // 5 - глубина очереди
            printf ("Error in listen\n"); return 0; }

        printf ("Server started!\n" );

        for (;;){
            struct sockaddr_in clientaddr;
            socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
            int  connfd=accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&clientaddr, &addrlen);

            printf ("Connection with connfd=%d from port=%d accepted!\n", connfd, clientaddr.sin_port);

            pid_t pid;
            if ((pid=fork())==0){   // fork раздваивает процесс

                close(listenfd);
                doit (connfd, clientaddr.sin_port);
                
                close (connfd);
                _exit(0);
            }
            close(connfd);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Да похоже сам запутался. т.е. новый сокет будет всегда с серверным 80 портом?

Comment: Да. Но Вы можете написать, насчет чего именно Вы сомневаетесь - тогда разберемся!

Comment: Меня интересует каким образом на 80 порту не создается очереди ведь получается огромное кол-во соединений общаются с сервером через 1 порт? Сейчас я начинаю догадываться что перед тем как переходить на обработку входящего соединение мы ищем сокет уже открытый от этого клиента и есть он есть направляем напрямую в этот сокет пакеты?

Comment: Да, именно так. С одним серверным портом моджет общаться огромное кол-во соединений одновременно. Я сейчас дополню ответ, чтобы сделать этот момент более понятным